# Defined a type family (++); any way to prove that (vs ++ us) ~ '[] implies (vs ~ '[]) and (us ~ '[])?

Tags: haskell, functional-dependencies, type-families

Defined:

```
type family (xs :: [*]) ++ (ys :: [*]) where
  '[] ++ ys = ys
  (x ': xs) ++ ys = x ': (xs ++ ys)
```

I have a GADT that's kinda like

```
data Foo :: [*] -> * -> * where
  Foo0 :: a -> Foo '[] a
  Foo1 :: Foo '[a] a
  Foo2 :: Foo vs a -> Foo us a -> Foo (vs ++ us) a
```

And I want to do something like

```
test :: Foo '[] Int -> Int
test (Foo0 x) = x
test (Foo2 x y) = test x + test y
```

But I can't use `test` on `x` or `y` because `x ~ Foo '[] Int` and `y ~ Foo '[] Int` have to be proven.  But I want to say that this is proven from the fact that `vs ++ us ~ '[]` means that the individual `vs` and `us` of `x` and `y` are necessarily `'[]`.

Is there any way to do this with type families, or maybe switching over to a multi param typeclass approach with fundeps?

Thanks!

Comment: Why even have the `[*]` index in your `Foo` GADT, if it's always equal to `[]`?

Comment: Pretend there's another constructor :)

Comment: Could you include the other constructors as well? The current set of constructors makes our job rather easy (see user3237465's answer below for reference).

Comment: @AndrásKovács ah, I see what you mean. I added another one... does this make a difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Don't touch the green smile!](https://twitter.com/pigworker/status/261219712501956609)

> The presence of ‘green slime’ — defined functions in the return types
>   of constructors — is a danger sign.

The simplest workaround is to generalize `test` and then instantiate:

```
gtest :: Foo xs Int -> Int
gtest (Foo0 x) = x
gtest (Foo2 x y) = gtest x + gtest y

test :: Foo '[] Int -> Int
test = gtest
```

Answer (score 4):

You could add two type families that would serve as inverses of `++`, and without loss of generality add them as constraints to the Foo2 constructor. Through those inverse type families GHC would be able to infer exactly what you're asking from it.

Here's an example implementation of `CutX` and `CutY` such that `r ~ a ++ b` <=> `a ~ CutY r b` <=> `b ~ CutX r a`.

```
type family (xs :: [*]) ++ (ys :: [*]) where
  '[] ++ ys = ys
  (x ': xs) ++ ys = x ': (xs ++ ys)

type family CutX (rs :: [*]) (xs :: [*]) where
    CutX '[] xs = '[]
    CutX rs '[] = rs
    CutX (r ': rs) (x ': xs) = CutX rs xs

type family ZipWithConst (xs :: [*]) (ys :: [*]) where
    ZipWithConst '[] ys = '[]
    ZipWithConst xs '[] = '[]
    ZipWithConst (x ': xs) (y ': ys) = y ': ZipWithConst xs ys

type CutY rs ys = ZipWithConst rs (CutX rs ys)

data Foo :: [*] -> * -> * where
  Foo0 :: a -> Foo '[] a
  Foo1 :: Foo '[a] a
  Foo2 :: (rs ~ (vs ++ us), us ~ CutX rs vs, vs ~ CutY rs us) => Foo vs a -> Foo us a -> Foo rs a
```

Comment: @AndrásKovács It might be that it was never used before. I discovered it not long ago myself and wrote an [article about it](http://mniip.com/pages/BidirectionalTypeFamilyInference).